# Google endpoint with datastore : java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I stuck on data store.

I am trying to run Google end point with data-store.

After `mvn appengine:update` command , I can see my methods on explorer  , but it is not getting execute as it is having  error.

Here is error :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Here is my function which i am trying to execute :

`@ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public Profile saveProfile(final User user, ProfileForm profileForm)
            throws UnauthorizedException {
        TeeShirtSize teeShirtSize = TeeShirtSize.NOT_SPECIFIED;
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
        }
        String userId = user.getUserId();
        String mainEmail = user.getEmail();
        String displayName = profileForm.getDisplayName();
        if (profileForm.getTeeShirtSize() != null) {
            teeShirtSize = profileForm.getTeeShirtSize();
        }
        if (displayName == null) {
            displayName = extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(user.getEmail());
        }
        Profile profile = new Profile(userId, displayName, mainEmail, teeShirtSize);ofy().save().entity(profile).now();
        return profile;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to register Objectify. Make a startup servlet like

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

public class StartupServlet extends HttpServlet {

  static {
    ObjectifyService.register(Profile.class);
  }
}
```

and register in in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>startup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>full.package.StartupServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Edit:

I suppose that you have imported ofy from google library again in your code snippet, change it to:

```
OfySevice.ofy().save().entity(profile).now();
```

Comment: I have created 1 file named "OfyService.java' ..here is a code of that file :

Comment: in this , i have included following things:package com.google.devrel.training.conference.service;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.domain.Profile;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

Comment: `public class OfyService {
     static {
        ObjectifyService.register(Profile.class);
    }
    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}`

Comment: then you probably forgot to run it

Comment: OfySevice.ofy().save().entity(profile).now();  after making changes , i am getting error for save method. -  cannot  find symbol : method save()

Comment: Just make a servlet instead of your helper class, you DO NOT initialize objectify with your helper class, of course you have exceptions